# Javascript to check validation and change textbox color

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, client-side-validation

Check out the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateTextBox(source, args) {
        var is_valid = false;

        //Regex goes here
        var regex = /^[a-z A-Z]+$/;
        var check = regex.test($('tbName').val()); //Checks the tbName value against the regex
        if (check == true) {
            //If input was correct
            is_valid = true;
        }
        else {
            //If input is not correct
            $("tbName").css(("background-color", "#A00000"), ("border-color", "#780000"));
        }
        args.IsValid = is_valid; //Returns validity state
    }
</script>
```

Im trying to check the input of a textbox so its only character between a and z, and A and Z, but it still returns true even on input like "1245".

Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: The value of `/^[a-z A-Z]+$/.test("1234")` is `false`, the problem isn't in your regex. Check what value you are passing to `test()`

Comment: Try inverting your regex to find anything that's NOT valid: `/[^a-z A-Z]/` and `if (check) { invalid }`. Right now your regex breaks if the input text is multiline.

Comment: Im trying to check the value i am passing, but it isnt working properly. Am i selecting the control properly?

Comment: Ok i managed to check the input by doing:

var test = $('#tbName').val();

And test contains "undefined". Does this mean the control was not found?

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but i found the problem. Scince i am using masterpages, the actual id was "ContentPlaceHolder1_tbName". Is there a cleaner way to select the control and ignore the placeholder appendix?

Answer (score 2):

`$('tbName')` may not be a valid selector.

Did you mean to select a class?

```
$(.tbName')
```

What about an element with an id=`tbName`?

```
$('#tbName')
```

Also, why do you need to do this? This will NOT be accessible outside of the function, as it is a local variable passed to the function (via its parameters)

```
args.IsValid = is_valid;
```

You can just do a simple return:

```
function ValidateTextBox() {
    var regex = /^[a-z A-Z]+$/;
    return regex.test($('#tbName').val());
}
```

Comment: Oh man im so new to javascript... how do i go about selecting a textbox with that ID?

Its shown here:

<asp:TextBox CssClass="block" ID="tbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: "Also, why do you need to do this? This will NOT be accessible outside of the function, as it is a local variable passed to the function (via its parameters)"

I need to check within the method to see if it matched, so i can change the textbox color. Didnt know you have to do "#" before a control id. Thanks!

Comment: I see, and what is the $ symbol for? Is it to tell javascript that the following line uses a JQuery method?